# Create Table with Group_Concat

Tags: group-concat

I have a table DATA with
meta_id post_id meta_key    meta-value

```
meta_id    post_id    meta_key    meta-value
1          20         country     AU
2          20         first_name  Fred
3          20         last_name   Smith
4          21         menu_item   Post_type
5          21         menu_object Page
6          22         country     AU
7          22         first_name  Jane
8          22         last_name   Brown
```

I want to create a new table RESULTS that contains only those post_id records with a meta_key of country and selectively select meta_values for that post_id – note the meta_key country is not a required result.  Post_id 21 is not selected as it does not have a meta_key of country.

The resultant output in the RESULT table would be:

```
unique_id, post_id, first_name, last_name
1 |20  | Fred  | Smith
2 | 22 | Jane  | Brown
```

I just cannot seem to get anywhere near a result with this.  Any thoughts as to how to derive the outcome?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my issue - no action required.